# Fastest way to create a JSON serializable image in node.js & place it on client canvas?

Tags: html, image, node.js, canvas, meteor

I'm building an app with meteor.js that requires dynamically generated images. A whole lot of small, dynamically generated images; generated pixel by pixel, they would collectively require  ~25000 pixels of image per second. Realizing that this is quite the computational load, I've decided to use Meteor's server methods to speed up the process.

As of now, here's my functional attempt:

Server-side generation of a pixel array

```
loadImage = function(){
    this.imagePixels = new Uint8Array(4*DIM*DIM);
    for(var i = 0; i < DIM; i++){
    for(var j = 0; j < DIM; j++){
        var x = 255*i/DIM;
        var y = 255*j/DIM;
        this.setPixel(this.imagePixels,
                      i, j, eval(this.redEQ)
                          , eval(this.greenEQ)
                          , eval(this.blueEQ)
                          , 255);
        }
    }
}
```

And then some intermediate stuff happens (code not shown), the data is sent back to client, and the following places the "image" onto the canvas via uint8array.set:

```
var elem = document.getElementById(this.canvasID);
var ctx = elem.getContext('2d');
var imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, DIM, DIM);
var data = imageData.data;
data.set(this.evo.pixels);
ctx.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
```

This is all fine and dandy except... I need speed. So, that being said, here's my question:

**Is it possible to create a JSON serializable image within node.js which can efficiently be placed on an HTML canvas and, if so, how?**

Comment: convert to jpg/png and set json property to base64 of jpeg/png?

Comment: where does your bottelneck lie? is it the image creation the transmission of data or the displaying on the client?

Comment: With some tweaking, it's now manageable. Although, if there is a standard method of image creation, I'd appreciate the info. As of now I'm just filling a canvas with pixel data; it would probably be faster if I could just place a png/jpg on the screen